# Unable to import Pandas in IPython 6.5.0 console (Spyder)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, kernel, ipython, spyder

After installing pandas am able to import in cmd as below :

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\Django_Project>python
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit    
(AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>>
```

But when am importing pandas in Spyder in IPython 6.5.0 console I get below error:

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\parentpoller.py:116: UserWarning: Parent poll failed.  If the frontend dies,
                the kernel may be left running.  Please let us know
                about your system (bitness, Python, etc.) at
                ipython-dev@scipy.org
  ipython-dev@scipy.org""")

In [1] : import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-38d4b0363d82>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

In [2] :
```

Note: I have installed python in "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\" path and environment variables is set as "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37;"

And I installed pandas using PIP

Please suggest the solution to resolve this issue.I have tried reinstalling the pandas package almost 6-7 times.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read [our guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) for this kind of problem to understand how to fix it. Also, if you're new to Python, we *strongly* recommend you to use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information you've provided.Am able to import it now.

Comment: Installing Anaconda as recommended

Answer (score 0):

I think you should open anaconda command prompt by searching it in windows search bar . Now write there "conda install -c anaconda pandas" and try again to run the program